# Instagram Graph API Get Follower Count

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm currently playing inside the Graph API Explorer to retrieve some data from the Instagram API.  My app is set up in Facebook Developer. All I want is to retrieve **followers_count** from a given username.

Inside the Graph API Explorer, I have connected my App, have an access token, and set up permissions per the Instagram API Reference page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/).

When I run my query inside the tool I'm getting an error that says I'm still missing permissions:

> "message": "(#100) Missing permissions",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 100,

I currently have set some extra permissions just to see if perhaps their documentation isn't up-to-date but still no luck:

- read_insights
- pages_show_list
- business_management
- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_insights
- pages_read_engagement

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `pages_read_user_content` and `pages_read_engagement`